# How to deserialize and serialize zonedDateTime in java

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, deserialization, zoneddatetime

I have an entity which has a `ZonedDateTime` attribute. I want that when using `jackson objectMapper` it deserializes it in the `ISO 8601 format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ in the UTC timezone`.

But when I'm trying to do it using that pattern, I'm giving `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too many pattern letters: s`.

After that I modified tha pattern to: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` getting the following error: `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2012-02-22T02:06:58.147+0200' could not be parsed at index 23`.

I tried to use custom serializers and deserializers but I'm having no desired results.

What I want to achieve is when I do `objectMapper.writeValueAsString(entity)` it prints me something like `2012-02-22T02:06:58.147Z` because I want to deserialize things like `2012-02-22T02:06:58.147Z`.

Any idea?

Comment: So you don’t want to serialize any time zone or offset information? It seems you’ve serialized an offset of `+0200`. Are you using [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) or not?

Comment: Based on the [DateTimeFormatter documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), you probably want to use `X` or `V` instead of `Z` in your format string.